# display only specific swagger API documentation endpoints with grape-swagger-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger-ui, ruby-grape

I have some REST endpoints (see example documentation below). They are created using grape-swagger-rails gem.
I want to show only specific endpoints and hide rest of them. Has anyone ideas on how do I approach this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write entity controller name to url.

`http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html#/pet-controller`

*8081: your server port*

*pet-controller: your controller name of its has endpoint.*